# WordPress search not working for particular word / It is working when I am manually add in URL

Tags: wordpress, search, redirect

Wordpress Search

1). www.example.com/?s=perticularword - **Not Working**

example particular word:"booking"

2). www.example.com/blog/?s=booking - Entered *manually* in URL **it is working**

3). If I am using the code - It returns too many redirections  - **Not Working**

```
function fb_change_search_url_rewrite() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/blog/?s=" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_change_search_url_rewrite' );
```

I want **www.example.com/blog/?s=booking** this search results **how to get results** ??

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is also true for your redirected url. Use

```
if ( ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) && stripos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'blog' ) === false ) {
```

to make the condition false on your redirected url.

Comment: No luck , I put this code but the url not redirect to www.example.com/blog/?s=booking it is redirect to www.example.com/?s=booking so no results..